# Exclude sw.js from the long term caching with glob pattern matching

Tags: firebase, pattern-matching, glob, firebase-hosting

In order to enable long term caching, per the Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config), I have this in the headers configuration:

```
"headers": [
  {
    "source": "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|js|css)",
    "headers": [
      {
        "key": "Cache-Control",
        "value": "max-age=172800"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But I'm also serving a sw.js (service worker) for the app, which I don't want to be cached at all. First thing that comes to mind is to exclude it from the glob matching, which I need help for. Otherwise, if you think there's a better way, do tell. Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified the pattern and added new one that specifies `no-cache` for the `sw.js`

```
"headers": [
  {
    "source": "**/!(sw).@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|js|css)",
    "headers": [{ "key": "Cache-Control", "value": "max-age=31536000" }]
  },
  {
    "source": "**/sw.js",
    "headers": [{ "key": "Cache-Control", "value": "no-cache" }]
  }
]
```